# sgl bigquery запросы group by

Tags: sql, bigquery

Пытаюсь посчитать уникальных user для country и выдает ошибку по ключу group

```
SELECT country,  count(distinct user) as count  FROM `alert-vista-232907.WP.AS` LIMIT 1000  group by country
```

> Syntax error: Unexpected keyword GROUP at [1:93]

а вот такой запрос посчитал без ошибок, для сравнения

```
select count(distinct user) as count from`alert-vista-232907.WP.AS` LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в порядке, `Limit` должен идти после `Group By`

```
SELECT country, count(distinct user) as count FROM alert-vista-232907.WP.AS GROUP BY country LIMIT 1000
```